# How can create function like this in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to create function like this. please help me to complete my function
if both are +ve

```
$a = 10;
$b = 6;
// do nothing just show same value 10 and 6 
// if $b is negetive
$a = 10;
$b = -3;
// get the value from $a show the value 7 (10 - 3)
// 0 if $a is negative 
$a = -2;
$b = 6;
// (little bit diffrent) get the double form $b of negative value and
// show the value 0 and 2(6-4)
```

i have tried with this but totally stopped at else code

```
// $a = something;
// $b = something;

if ($a >0 && $b >0) {
  echo $a.' , '.$b;
}else{ 
  // what? what? what?
}
```

Comment: chaos in your minds. read books to understand basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
<?php
if ($a > 0) {
    if ($b > 0) echo $a." ".$b;
    else echo ($a+$b)." 0";
}
else {
    if ($b > 0) echo "0 ".($b+$a*2);
    //else undefined?
}
?>
```

Looks a bit homeworky though

Comment: thanks again for ur answer but i got a problem that not ur mistake my question was worng. in ur script if $a = -2 and $b = 1 its display 0 and -3 that is the problem. positive value cant be negative i have to show -1.5 and 0 in that case. so what is the solution for that.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say there, all of this is as basic as it gets, so try learning the basics of php scripting and give it a go yourself.

Comment: this is the code what i want <?php
$a = -7;
$b = 4;
if($a >0){
 if($b >0){
  echo $a." ".$b;
 }else{
  $c=$a+$b;
  if ($c >0){
   echo ($a+$b)."0";
  }else{
   echo "0".($a+$b);
   }
 }
}else{
 if($b >0) {
  if (($b+$a*2)>0){
   echo "0".($b+$a*2);
  }else{
   echo ($b/2+$a)."0"; 
  }
 }
}
?>